# How can I label the intersecting part of the venn diagram?

Tags: miktex, texmaker, venn-diagrams

```
        \begin{tikzpicture}[fill=gray]
        % left hand
        \scope
        \clip (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2)
              (1,0) circle (1);
        \fill (0,0) circle (1);
        \endscope
        % right hand
        \scope
        \clip (-2,-2) rectangle (2,2)
              (0,0) circle (1);
        \fill (1,0) circle (1);
        \endscope
        % outline
        \draw (0,0) circle (1) (0,1)  node [text=black,above](A) {$L(A)$}
              (1,0) circle (1) (1,1)  node [text=black,above](B) {$L(B)$}
              (-2,-2) rectangle (3,2) node [text=black,above] {$H$};
        \node[below] at (barycentric cs:A=1/2,B=1/2 ) {$A \cap B$};%I don't know how to orient here
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}

I want the intersecting portion to be labeled as
```

Comment: Thanks for providing code. Please complete the example so we can compile it!

Comment: Are you aware that there are packages for drawing Venn diagrams? So you don't have to do this the hard way if you don't want to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like so?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{venndiagram}

\begin{document}

\begin{venndiagram2sets}[labelAB={$A\cap B$},overlap=1cm]
\end{venndiagram2sets}
\end{document}
```

**Make sure you have an updated version of this package.**

[image]